# shell to have certain words hilighted

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal

I'd like to have certain key-words hilighted in my gnome-terminal window like "error".

Is it possible to configure gnome-terminal or zsh in such a way it will hilight these words (no matter which program displayed these words) ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=terminal+colour & https://superuser.com/search?q=terminal+color

Comment: VTE (GNOME Terminal) had a proof of concept patch a few years ago: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7771#note_1175694 . It worked nicely, but was never completed (to make the rules configurable rather than hardcoded), and never made it upstream. I don't know if the patch still applies. You might want to give that a try.